# find the nearest neighbors and itself within the boundary

Tags: java, arrays

given the matrix:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

i want to have the neighbors and itself within the boundary.For example, the col = 0 and row =0 should contain {1,2, 4, 5}

My code is :

```
pixel[0] = new Color(image.getRGB(col, row));
pixel[1] = new Color(image.getRGB(col + 1, row));
pixel[2] = new Color(image.getRGB(col, row + 1));
pixel[3] = new Color(image.getRGB(col + 1, row + 1));
pixel[4] = new Color(0);
pixel[5] = new Color(0);
pixel[6] = new Color(0);
pixel[7] = new Color(0);
pixel[8] = new Color(0);
```

my following code returns value of 0 and it makes {1,2, 4, 5,0,0,0,0}. How can I remove the value 0 in the array? should I just write like

```
pixel[8] = null;
```

Comment: Surely that code won't work for col=1 row=1?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the length of a Java array.

You have two options:

- Use `java.util.List` ([Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)):
  This interface have the methods `add` and `remove` and you can manipulate the elements with it.
- The next option is create new arrays each time you want to change its length.